# Echo command doesn't do anything

Tags: php, echo

I've been started studying PHP in my spare time, and the first code example I was given was this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo "Hello World";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

From what I understand, this should write out "Hello World". However, all I see is a blank webpage. Any ideas why this is and how I should go about fixing it?

Comment: What does viewing the source of the web page reveal?

Comment: Viewing the source just shows the same code as above.

Comment: any solutions to this? I have the same problem! I'm very new to php and I have a index.php on my desktop which does not work

Comment: @AdamP - Did you ever find the solution? I'm curious. My initial thought was it wasn't a .php file, but I see that it was. Was it because you didn't have PHP properly enabled on your machine?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a checklist

- What server are you running? Does it support php?
- Is PHP enabled?
- Is your file named with the extension .php?
- When you use View Source can you see the code in the php tags? If so PHP is not enabled

As a test try saving this as info.php

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and see if it displays information about your server

Comment: I am using an FTP server from my local ISP. When I view the source, I can see the code in the php tags, so I guess that means PHP isn't enabled. Is there something

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file that contains that code is a PHP file - ends in '.php'.

Comment: And that the web server is configured to actually run it through PHP. If he's on a web host, that *should* be done for him, but if he's setting up a server at home it might not be.

Comment: The file does have a .php extension and I'm on a web server so I don't think either of those are the problem. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to enable your error reporting in `.htacess` file in public_html folder and try to diagnose the issue depending upon the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems fine, certainly it should do what you intend.

Probably what happened is that you named the file with something like *example.html*, so you have to check the extension. It must look like *example.php*. With the extension .php at the end of the file you are telling the webserver that this file contains php code in it. That way the `<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>` is going to be interpreted and do you intend it to do.

Comment: I've already checked that the file has a .php extension several times, so I doubt that that is the problem. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the `html` tags in the source, it means there is a PHP error. Check your view source, and if nothing is shown, check your error logs.

Comment: Viewing the source shows the original code I posted above with `html` tags included.

Comment: Then make sure .php files are set to run with PHP.

Comment: Try adding each of these (one at a time) to a .htaccess `AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
AddHandler cgi-php5 .php` See: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=501583